# Creating Hive table for sub partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have one hive table with date partitioned. These dates start from 2017-01-01.

HDFS locations is date partitioned.

How can I create a Hive table considering only 5 dates from above HDFS location?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have multiple files in HDFS location that are specific to each partition i.e date in this regard.
So now you want to load the data for only 5 specific dates into the Hive table that you have created?

Comment: Do you want the new table as well to be partitioned

Comment: @Joby I have multiple files in HDFS date wise location. When we say partitioned it should have the format as (HDFS_LOC/create_date=2017-10-19), but my HDFS location is (HDFS_LOC/2017-10-19) .Now i want to create a process which will create a hive table. This hive table will have last 5 dates prior to process run date from above HDFS  date wise location.

Comment: @ImmanuelFredrick When we say partitioned it should have the format as (HDFS_LOC/create_date=2017-10-19), but my HDFS location is (HDFS_LOC/2017-10-19) . And new hive table to be created with last 5 dates prior to process run date from above my HDFS date location (Loc1: HDFS_LOC/2017-10-25; Loc2: HDFS_LOC/2017-10-24 ; HDFS_LOC/2017-10-23; HDFS_LOC/2017-10-22; HDFS_LOC/2017-10-21)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table newtable as select column1, column2, column3 from oldtable where  DateStamp >= '2017-01-01' and  DateStamp <= '2017-01-05'
```

Comment: here oldtable is your hive table with partition by date and DateStamp  is date as you mansion above.

Comment: you can create table and directly load the  partition file from hdfs  but this is more suitable and easy method. As you know if you manually load partition data files then It will removed from the source folder and shifted to new tables's folder.

Comment: DateStamp IN (‘ 2017-01-01’, ‘ 2017-01-03’,  2017-01-05’)  in case date in not in range.

Comment: You should edit your question to include new information, not comment on it.

Comment: My HDFS location is (HDFS_LOC/date_value). date value is starting from 2017-01-01 date. Like (HDFS_LOC/2017-01-01, HDFS_LOC/2017-01-02.......HDFS_LOC/2017-10-25). And when process runs to create new hive table it should consider last 5 dates prior to process run date and pick locations from above HDFS to create new hive table. So new hive table will have location startinng from (HDFS_LOC/2017-10-21) (HDFS_LOC/2017-10-22).....(HDFS_LOC/2017-10-25)

Comment: @KamleshKhollam you have to add this condition only  `DateStamp >= '2017-01-01' and  DateStamp <= '2017-01-05'`

Comment: @sahildesai how to assign "DateStamp" to date value if the HDFS Locations is /user/sales/2017-01-01.

Comment: @KamleshKhollam most probably It's partitions so you don't have to worry about it you just need to call main table so partitions will be loaded in to the table.

Comment: @sahildesai we do not have any partition created. Every time a process creates a HDFS lcoations as : /user/sales/date_value

Comment: @KamleshKhollam do one thing. go to your hive and check  `show partitions sales;` so It will so you all the dates.

Comment: Got the Error "Table sales is not a partitioned table"